# Regular expression to find substring

Tags: regex

I have an HTML file with a bunch of tags from exporting a file from LibreOffice.

The tags need to be deleted/replaced depending on what type they are.

What would be the regular expression string to find the following two examples?

```
</span><span class="T23">
</span><span class="T4">
```

I've got this code which finds the first bit up to the T:

```
\b</span><span class="T?\b
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<\/span><span class="T(\d+)">`

https://regex101.com/r/zT8aK9/2

This will find the number of what type it is. So based on your example input, it will return `23` and `4`.